# Migration from Aura Site to LWR

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, aura, lwr, experience

We are migrating our Aura site to o LWR Site and we encountered some "porting" problems between the two sites.

- Embedded chat is not supported on LWR
- Topics and articles cannot be used as i see. Do i have to recreate everything in the Digital Experience app,or can i use the old Topics and articles in some other way?

How can we make a workaround for this?
I don't find any suitable options throug the web.